# Mongo grouping - if-then filtering within aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to group the following fields and filter based on the grouping.

Example:

```
Document 1 { Id = 1, Name = X, Subject = A}
Document 2 { Id = 1, Name = X, Subject = B}
Document 3 { Id = 1, Name = X, Subject = A}
```

So the grouping should be Id, Name and If Subjects contains A push A else push B

In the above case it would be 1, X, A

Only one of the 3 values is needed but not able to get this with the following query.

```
db.getCollection('Students').aggregate([
{ $project:
        {
        "_id": 0,
        "Name": 1,
        "Id":1,
        "FilteredSubject": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": {"$eq": ["$Subject","A"]},
                "then":"A",
                "else":"B"                
            }          
        }
        } 
    },
   { $match: 
    {"Name":{$eq: "X"}}
   }
},
    { $group:
     {  _id: {"Id":"$Id", "Name": "$Name"},
        Result: {"$push":"$FilteredSubject"}
     }
    }
    ])
```

I'm getting the following result with both subjects pushed into the array instead of the if-else condition pushing just one from the grouping.

Actual result:

```
"result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "Id" : 1,
                "Name" : "X"
            },
            "FilteredSubject" : [ 
                A, 
                B, 
        ]
```

Expected result:

```
"result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "Id" : 1,
                "Name" : "X",
                "FilteredSubject" : "A"
            }
         }]
```

Comment: What would you be expecting? Why would you expect something else? You are basically asking *"If this contains this value then return that same value, otherwise return something else"*, which is exactly what is happening. Are you instead just wanting to create an array containing only "A"? If so, then also note that you have three documents so there is currently no reason why the result would not include `[ "A", "B", "A" ]` in the result, unless you are looking for a "set", which is a different operator.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to create a newField containing only "A" if one exists else only "B" if "A" does not exist. I looked at $set but not sure if there is a way to say $set newField = A if Array contains A else newField = B. Is there a way to get " if Array contains A" where the Array is [ "A", "B", "A" ]?

Comment: Your comment here makes things even less clear than your question. `$set` is an "update" operator used to modify the document permanently. The `.aggregate()` method does not modify documents, but just returns a result. Take some time and use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35188692/edit) link on your question to show a real set of documents and the real result you expect to achieve.

Comment: Based on your comment I think it is not possible to get the "Expected Result" shown above using an aggregate method since it will not modify documents. This might be something I have to do on the application side after retrieving the ["A","B","A"]. I was wondering if I could do this on the Mongo side though since I thought that would reduce the data returned to the application since that array could be huge.